# Call external function without sending 'self' arg

Tags: python

I'm writing tests for a Django application and using a attribute on my test class to store which view it's supposed to be testing, like this:

```
# IN TESTS.PY
class OrderTests(TestCase, ShopTest):
    _VIEW = views.order

    def test_gateway_answer(self):
        url = 'whatever url'
        request = self.request_factory(url, 'GET')
        self._VIEW(request, **{'sku': order.sku})


# IN VIEWS.PY
def order(request, sku)
    ...
```

My guess is that the problem I'm having is caused because since I'm calling an attribute of the `OrderTests` class, python assumes I wanna send `self` and then `order` get the wrong arguments. Easy to solve... just not use it as a class attribute, but I was wondering if there's a way to tell python to not send self in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that what you have here is an instance method, not a class method.  It's an important distinction, the understanding of which will help you to fix your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because in Python functions are [*descriptors*](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors), so when they are accessed on class instances they bind their first (assumed `self`) parameter to the instance.

You could access `_VIEW` on the class, not on the instance:

```
class OrderTests(TestCase, ShopTest):
    _VIEW = views.order

    def test_gateway_answer(self):
        url = 'whatever url'
        request = self.request_factory(url, 'GET')
        OrderTests._VIEW(request, **{'sku': order.sku})
```

Alternatively, you can wrap it in [`staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#staticmethod) to prevent it being bound to the instance:

```
class OrderTests(TestCase, ShopTest):
    _VIEW = staticmethod(views.order)

    def test_gateway_answer(self):
        url = 'whatever url'
        request = self.request_factory(url, 'GET')
        self._VIEW(request, **{'sku': order.sku})
```

Comment: Cool! I knew about `@staticmethod` but didn't know it could be used as a function (which was dumb of me, now that I think of it, but hey...) Thank you so much!